# How to make an horizontally large table fit into the output?

Tags: tables

I am trying to fit an horizontally large table in the PDF output... Acting on the size inches of each column does not help so far. Any suggestion?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
%\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}


\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%
   \setul{}{3.5ex}% increased by 1ex
   \let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor
   \dimen@\SOUL@ulthickness
   \dimen@i=-.75ex % increased by -0.25ex
   \advance\dimen@i-.5\dimen@
   \edef\SOUL@uldepth{\the\dimen@i}%
   \let\SOUL@ulcolor\SOUL@stcolor
   \SOUL@ulpreamble
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sectionbiblio}{%
   \patchcmd{\std@thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}
}


% define \c
%citetpos just like \citet
\DeclareRobustCommand\citetpos
{\begingroup
   \let\NAT@nmfmt\NAT@posfmt% ...except with a different name format
   \NAT@swafalse\let\NAT@ctype\z@\NAT@partrue
   \@ifstar{\NAT@fulltrue\NAT@citetp}{\NAT@fullfalse\NAT@citetp}}

\makeatother

\makeatletter
% make numeric styles use name format
\patchcmd{\NAT@test}{\else \NAT@nm}{\else \NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}{}{}

\let\NAT@orig@nmfmt\NAT@nmfmt
\def\NAT@posfmt#1{\NAT@orig@nmfmt{#1's}}

\makeatother
\newcommand{\Y}[1]{{\color{green}#1}}
\newcommand{\N}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.9}


\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{{\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=45\relax\hl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
   \centering
   \caption{DDQRL}\label{tab:2}
   \begin{tabular}{p{1.5in} p{0.3in} p{0.3in} p{0.3in} p{0.3in} p{0.3in} p{0.3in} p{0.3in} p{0.3in} p{0.3in} p{0.3in} p{0.3in}} 
   ~ & \textbf{} & \textbf{D1} & \textbf{D2} & \textbf{D3} & \textbf{D4} & \textbf{D5}& \textbf{D6}& \textbf{D7}& \textbf{D8}& \textbf{D9}& \textbf{D10}& \textbf{Average}\\ 
   Annualized mean (\%) & 16.46 & 16.03 & 14.16 & 15.79 & 16.4 & 16.10 & 15.9 & 15.74 & 15.80 & 15.4 & 15.81\\  
   Annualized median & 16.47\% & 17.43\% & 8.72\% & 7.18\% & 11.38\% \\  
   Annualized st. deviation & 12.93\% & 12.70\% & 10.46\% & 10.82\% & 16.44\% \\  
   Downside volatility & 0.92 & 0.87 & 0.83 & 1.08 & 0.95 \\  
   Skewness & -1.46 & -1.46 & -1.41 & -0.62 & -0.94 \\  
   Kurtosis & 5.53 & 5.27 & 7.76 & 4.07 & 8.01 \\  
   Volatility Skewness & 0.92 & 0.87 & 0.83 & 1.08 & 0.95 \\  
   Sharpe Ratio & 1.3 & 1.42 & 0.83 & 0.66 & 0.64 \\  
   Sortino Ratio & 0.24 & 0.26 & 0.162 & 0.157 & 0.133 \\  
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Please, consider the first row of the table, as I did not fill in the rest yet.

Comment: Off-topic: `left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm` may be simplified to either `margin=2.54cm` or `margin=1in`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx} % considered is v3

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\footnotesize
\sisetup{table-format=-1.2,
        table-space-text-post={\%},
        }
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.2pt}
\caption{DDQRL}\label{tab:2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X *{11}{S} @{}}
   \toprule
    & {\thead{D1}} & {\thead{D2}} & {\thead{D3}} & {\thead{D4}} & {\thead{D5}}
    & {\thead{D6}} & {\thead{D7}} & {\thead{D8}} & {\thead{D9}} & {\thead{D10}}
    & {\thead{Average}}                                                     \\   
    \midrule                                                                
Annualized mean (\%) 
    & 16.46   & 16.03   & 14.16   & 15.79    & 16.4 
    & 16.10   & 15.9    & 15.74   & 15.80    & 15.4   & 15.81               \\
Annualized median 
    & 16.47\% & 17.43\% &  8.72\% &  7.18\% & 11.38\% &   &   &   &   &   & \\
Annualized st. deviation 
    & 12.93\% & 12.70\% & 10.46\% & 10.82\% & 16.44\% &   &   &   &   &   & \\
Downside volatility 
    & 0.92    & 0.87    & 0.83    & 1.08    & 0.95    &   &   &   &   &   & \\
Skewness 
    & -1.46   & -1.46   & -1.41   & -0.62   & -0.94   &   &   &   &   &   & \\
Kurtosis 
    & 5.53    & 5.27    & 7.76    & 4.07    & 8.01    &   &   &   &   &   & \\
Volatility Skewness 
    & 0.92    & 0.87    & 0.83    & 1.08    & 0.95    &   &   &   &   &   & \\
Sharpe Ratio 
    & 1.3     & 1.42    & 0.83    & 0.66    & 0.64    &   &   &   &   &   & \\
Sortino Ratio 
    & 0.24    & 0.26    & 0.162   & 0.157   & 0.133   &   &   &   &   &   & \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]